# smarty function with single argument

Tags: smarty, smarty3, smarty2

I want to use the following custom smarty function:

```
function smarty_function_heading($params){
  return $params[0]->getHeading(LANG);
}
```

In my Template I try to use this function in the following way:

```
{heading $page}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "test.smarty" on line 19 "<h1>{heading $page}</h1>" too many shorthand attributes <-- thrown in smarty-3.1.16/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 19
```

Can someone tell me the right way to use a smarty function with a single argument?

### Thanks!

Notice: I know how to use a smarty function this way: {heading page=$page} but I don't want to do it this way. Hope someone has an idea.

Comment: How does your `$params` array look like? It seems, that are are passing a multi-dimensional-array as `$params`.

Try something like this, so that your `$page` is a flatline-array.
`$page = array($page)`

Answer (score 1):

You may not want (for some reason) to do it this way, but this is how functions work in Smarty.

You can try to create a modifier instead, i.e. `{$page|heading}`